# Why does git init create metadata folders in root directory instead of .git?

Tags: linux, git, filesystems

My cd is the working directory of the (desired) git repository.
Whenever I do `git init` it does not create the `.git` folder with all its metadata. Instead, it just places the metadata folders `branches`, `hooks`, `refs` etc. in the working directory **directly**.

How to configure git to utilize the `.git` repository again?

Moving the files to `.git` does not solve the problem. If I do this, the folder does not get recognized as working directory anymore.

Comment: Sounds like a [bare repository](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+bare+repository).

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the output of `git config -l` as a text block when run outside of any repository?

Answer (score -1):

You seem to have cloned a bare repository. Please re-clone without the `--bare` switch. Or, you can clone into a different folder from this clone (again without the `--bare` switch) to get the latest contents resurrected

Comment: The OP didn't clone.